# Shell script returning non zero value after killing process

Tags: bash, shell, kill-process

I am trying to kill a process using a shell script.Looks shell itself is getting killed in this process. Also I am seeing non zero return value of the script in terminal.

I am running it on Amazon Linux 2 with sudo.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep myapp | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
```

I am executing like:

```sh
sudo ./myscript.sh
```

"echo $?" after executing is returning 137 instead of zero. Can someone please help to understand what is going wrong.

Another observation:
if i directly run kill command in my terminal, i.e below command,

```sh
kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep myapp | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
```

I see echo $? is returning zero.

**Update:**
Problem is solved. Name of process I am trying to kill is overlapping with name of my script. Hence grep is returning both the pid's. Both the process are getting killed. Also learnt that better way of doing this by using pkill or using pidof() to get pid.

Comment: I would verify what `kill` really is killing here by doing a `set -x` before running the command and checking its output.

Comment: This is a festering pile of antipatterns. You want `pkill` and you really want to avoid the `-9`

Comment: `grep myapp | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'` = `awk '/[m]yapp/{print $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the exit code of your last-run command to be the exit code for the script, your script must end with exit $? as the last line.  Any function before that must also end with the $? so the chain flows to that final line.  Otherwise some other exit is taking place.

If the script is being killed along side the application or script you are trying to kill, then your ps and grep work is likely including both in the results.  Look at the output of the ps and grep while the script is running.  You could add a line prior to your kill line which just shows the output of the ps and greps so you can see what is actually getting killed.

Finally (and I don't think this is the case) if you are trying to end the script after the kill, manually run an exit (again likely using exit $? for the reason stated above) where appropriate within the script.

Hope that helps you get where you are going.

Comment: If the script is being killed along side the application or script you are trying to kill, then your ps and grep work is likely including both in the results -> This is correct. Name of process I am trying to kill overlaps with name of my script. hence both are getting killed. Thanks a lot for your answer,

Comment: You will find style guides which recommend naming your shell scripts as scriptName.sh as this avoids just such situations as you have found yourself.  Our style guide at work requires that we end our scripts in .sh and I consider it a best-practice.  

Please remember to mark this as your accepted answer if it did fix your issue.  Thanks!